# Render images from Entries in Contenful + Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, contentful

The issues:

1. How to I access the `includes` array so I can get the image url to render the image? (or how to I get the images to render in general)
2. Why is are my `description` fields not rendering?

So I have a contentful service that gets all the entries as such:

```js
  //get all exhibits
  getExhibits(query?: object): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.cdaClient.getEntries(Object.assign({
      include : 2,
      content_type: CONFIG.contentTypeIds.exhibit
    }, query))
      .then(res => res.items);
  }
```

The above function is called in my Gallery component as such:

```html
  ngOnInit() {
    this.contentfulService.getExhibits()
    .then(exhibits => this.exhibits = exhibits);
  }
```

And the data is rendered in the corresponding HTML as such:

```html
<section class="gallery__section" [class.menu--open]="menu.isMenuClosed" *ngFor="let exhibit of exhibits">
 <figure>
  <img src="{{ exhibit.fields.file.url }}" alt="">
    <!-- HOW DO I GET THE IMG URL -->
 </figure>
 <div class="gallery__text">
  <h2 class="gallery__heading">Gallery</h2>
  <p class="gallery__title">{{ exhibit.fields.title }}</p>
  <h3 class="gallery__artist">{{ exhibit.fields.artist }}</h3>
  <p class="gallery_onview">On View</p>
  <p class="gallery__dates">{{ exhibit.fields.date }}</p>
  <p class="gallery__description" *ngIf="exhibit.fields.description.content[0].content[0].value">{{ exhibit.fields.description.content[0].content[0].value }}</p>
 </div>
</section>
```

Bellow is the JSON of one `item` the `items` array:

[image]

And here the image that is supposed be part of the above `item`, but is placed in a different array called `includes`:

[image]

Below is the `console.log` output of one exhibit:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to access the `includes` array. The Contentful SDK will automatically resolve the fields that contain a reference.

For your image issue, I think you're missing the field name for your file field: `exhibit.fields.YOUR_FIELD_NAME.fields.file.url`

For your description field, I would recommend using [ngx-contentful-rich-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-contentful-rich-text) to parse the rich text into HTML.

Comment: Your image suggestion did not do the trick. As per `ngx-contentful-rich-text` I would rather hold off on that now. I should able to render the text as it is too no? I have added screenshots of the JSON of one item. Maybe this will give you more insight.

Comment: I assume those screenshots are from your browser's network logs. Can you also log out the value of `this.exhibits` in your component? The SDK will automatically add the file from the `includes` array into your `photo` field. So the value of `this.exibits` will not be identical to the response returned from Contenful's API. This is the link resolution feature: https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#link-resolution

Comment: Perfect! The images are working now, I am still having issues rendering the description. Indeed the above was the brower's network log, I have added also the console log output of one exhibit. My attempt was `exhibit.fields.description.content[0].content[0].value`, but that is not working.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have so it should work. Are you getting any JavaScript errors in your console? I can't really help more with that one. I would just suggest debugging that in your component to see if you can access the value.

Comment: Alright thank! You hvae answered the inital question for me and the images work now!